# How to install sent2vec module?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to install `sent2vec` on Amazon EC2. However, I think there's something wrong in what I am doing.

How can I achieve this objective?

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps I followed in my **local environment**.

After running the following commands

```
conda activate <the environment name here>
git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
cd fastText
pip install .
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec.git
cd sent2vec
pip install .
```

it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I found it out myself.

Download the zipped version from github.

1. `wget https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec/archive/master.zip`
2. `unzip master.zip`
3. `make`
4. `sudo python3.7 -m pip install .` ( I am using python3.7, hence mentioned. you can try `sudo pip install .` also. )

(if you fail at step 4, try this as well `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev`)

That's it!